# mysql query for getting a list of items with reference to another table

Tags: mysql, mariasql

i have table like this

```
+----+-------+-------------+
| id | items |     name    |
+----+-------+-------------+
|  1 | 1,2,3 |   hot deals |
|  2 | 2,3,4 |   offers    |
+----+-------+-------------+
```

where items are the id of product

here is the product table (mini version)

```
+-----------+--------------------+
| productid |  productname       |
+-----------+--------------------+
|         1 |   sony mobile      |
|         2 |   iphone 4s        |
|         3 |   dell laptop v1   |
|         4 |   samsung mouse    |
+-----------+--------------------+
```

i need to get result as array of items with name 
ex
[hot deals =>[(1,sony mobile),(2,iphone 4s),(3,dell laptop v1 )
],offers=>[--]]

can achieve this in (**MYSQL**)stored procedure if not how can i achieve this with minimum numberof queries 
side note:first table will have maximum of 6 rows

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `join` with `find_in_set()`:

```
select t.id, t.name, p.productname
from yourtable t
   join products p on find_in_set(p.productid, t.items)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ac7c/1)

As a side note, I'd recommend looking into database normalization.  Better to create another 1-n table to store the comma separated values separately.